# Clicking on different cells showing numbers in increasing order

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to setup a vba code with this characteristics: 
When I click on any cell, the number "1" appears. And then, when I click on another cell I get the number "2", and so on. Is there any way of doing this?

This is my attempt, but it obviously works very differently than what I want to do.
Here, when I click on a cell it always starts from 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal countCell As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
countCell = countCell + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Understand your question correctly, then the following code should give you what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range(Cells.Address), Target) Is Nothing Then
LastClick = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells.Address))
ActiveCell.Value = LastClick + 1
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: The above code will also trigger a new value if a new cell is selected with the arrow keys, which probably isn't exactly what you want.  The following code will work following a double-click of the mouse, unfortunately I can't work out how to trigger the event on a single click.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    LastClick = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells.Address))
    ActiveCell.Value = LastClick + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer the [BDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick) version. If you add `Cancel = True` it will prevent the [Application.DoubleClick method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.doubleclick)'s default action.

Comment: The first one works perfectly for what I need, you are a genius men, thank you very much